# Sending private info to users through a Facebook application

Tags: facebook

Is there a way of sending personalized private information to users through API/FB app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have it currently disabled for the legacy messaging system but it appears for the new messaging system they are allowing it again.  You probably have to log in, but here is the link.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

Answer (score 0):

When the user registers with your site you can request the user_email permission to get their email address and you could email them.